# getting facebook post impression that was sent via website app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

is there a way to retrieve impressions of a post that was made via my app? I've fetched the insights for my app, but don't know how to get the post id, and retrieve "insights" for that post-id (like: impressions, activity on this post, etc).

Is there a way to achieve this throught graph api?

Thanks,
Ramo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insights are only available to apps, domains and pages and for page's posts.

> The Page, Application and Domain objects have an insights connection
>   of this type. Post objects also have this connection where the Post
>   was made by a Page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#analytics

and

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

`http://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID_OF_A_PAGE_POST/insights/INSIGHT_NAME?access_token=ValidPageAccessToken`

Comment: Hi, but how do i get POST_ID_OF_A_PAGE_POST ?

Comment: Directly via the graph objects using `http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed` or you can query the FQL stream table as an alternative.  Happy Coding!